# Is it possible to get access token through azure graph and use it to access azure storage accounts?

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage-account

For instance I can authenticate through graph api by getaccesstokencredentials(username, password)
Can I use this token to access Azure?
Current we can use usertokencredentials and applicationtokencredentials from management library then once done you can create instance of azure class.
Azure azure = Azure.authenticate(credentials).withdefaultsubscription.
I'm wondering if we can use the token from getaccesstokencredentials instead of usertokentcredentials and applicationtokencredentials

Comment: Could you please provide the code of how to call graph api or provide the document regrading ```getaccesstokencredentials```?

Comment: This is the code to get the access token through gazure graph

Comment: getAccessTokenFromUserCredentials(
            String uname, String pwd) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationContext ctx;
        AuthenticationResult res;
        ExecutorService service = null;
        try {
            service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
            ctx= new AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY, false, service);
            Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken(
                    "https://graph.microsoft.com", appid, uname, pwd,
                    null);
            res= future.get();
        } 
        res result;
    }

Comment: Removed some part since it is very long

Comment: We use following code to authenticate in azure:   UserTokenCredentials creds = new UserTokenCredentials(
                    CLIENT_ID,
                    domain,
                    username,
                    password,
                    AzureEnvironment.AZURE);  Azure azureAuth = Azure.authenticate(creds).withDefaultSubscription(); I'm thinking of using the token generated through graph api instead of the token from usertokencredentials, because if I authenticate using usertokencredentials I'm getting "invalid_grant" issue but when using graph it's successful

Comment: We cannot use the same access token to call graph api and call api to manage Azure resource. Because the resource url for graph api is ```https://graph.microsoft.com``` but the resource url for Azure management rest api is ```https://management.core.windows.net/```. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-api-authentication.

Comment: I see, now I understand. All good now. thanks Jim Xu!

Comment: Since your issue has been resolved, could you please accept the answer? This can help other community members. Thank you.

Comment: So may I know your target pls ? You just want to generate an Azure object only or access files in your storage account via Azure AD auth ?

Comment: I want to access files in my storage account via Azure AD auth.

Comment: Well actually both, first I want to create object of Azure after using UserTokenCredentials and use it's object to access the storage accounts.

Comment: Now I'm able to authenticate using a given username and password where the Azure app belongs. Then I want to use the client id of this app so that other users can also be authenticated. 
Say I have the ff info, both usernames A and B should be authenticated with just one clientID:

constantClientID
usernameA
passwordA

usernameB
passwordB

Comment: //This is successful
 UserTokenCredentials creds = new UserTokenCredentials(
                    constantClientID,
                    domain,
                    usernameA,
                    passwordA,
                    AzureEnvironment.AZURE);

//This is not successful
  UserTokenCredentials creds = new UserTokenCredentials(
                    constantClientID,
                    domain,
                    usernameB,
                    passwordB,
                    AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
Is there any permission I need to set in my App to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot use the the same access token to call graph api and call api to manage Azure resource. Because the resource url for graph api is`https://graph.microsoft.com/` but the resource url for Azure management rest api is `https://management.azure.com/`. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-api-authentication.

Besides, regarding how to use Azure AD to access Azure storage, please refer to the following steps:

1. Add role assignment to your principal.

[image]

2. Get token.

   ```
   public static String getToken() throws Exception {
       String TENANT_ID = "your tenant id or name, e4c9*-*-*-*-*57fb";
       String AUTHORITY = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + TENANT_ID;
       String CLIENT_ID = "your application id, dc17*-*-*-*a5e7";
       String CLIENT_SECRET = "the secret, /pG*32";
       String RESOURCE = "https://storage.azure.com/";
       String ACCESS_TOKEN = null;
       ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
       AuthenticationContext context = null;
       try {
           context = new AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY, false, service);
           ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
           Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken(RESOURCE, credential, null);
           ACCESS_TOKEN = future.get().getAccessToken();
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (ExecutionException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } finally {
           service.shutdown();
       }
       return ACCESS_TOKEN;
   }
   ```
3. Access blob.

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       String token = getToken();
       StorageCredentialsToken credentialsToken = new StorageCredentialsToken("storagetest789", token);
       CloudBlobClient blobClient = new CloudBlobClient(new URI("https://storagetest789.blob.core.windows.net/"), credentialsToken);
       CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.getContainerReference("pub");
       CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = blobContainer.getBlockBlobReference("test1.txt");
       blockBlob.uploadText("mytest");
   }
   ```

For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad.